# I need help creating a new TFS project. I'm getting a Reporting Services error

Tags: tfs, reporting-services

I recently inherited control of our TFS server.  I am trying to create a new TFS project and get an error.  Any help or clues to how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the exception message that is logged.

```
---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2010-06-22 11:09:47Z
Module: Initializer
Event Description: TF30207: Initialization for plugin "Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.Reporting" failed
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
Exception Message: TF30224: Failed to retrieve projects from the report server. Please check that the SQL Server Reporting Services Web and Windows services are running and you have sufficient privileges for creating a project.
Exception Details: The Project Creation Wizard encountered a problem while creating reports on the SQL Server Reporting Services on DELTADEV. 
The reason for the failure cannot be determined at this time. 
Because the operation failed, the wizard was not able to finish creating the SQL Server Reporting Services site.
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.RosettaReportUploader.CheckForProjectFolder(PrivateData data, String projectName, ProjectCreationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.RosettaReportUploader.Initialize(ProjectCreationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.EngineStarter.InitializePlugins(MsfTemplate template, PcwPluginCollection pluginCollection)
--   Inner Exception   --
Exception Type: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException
Exception Message: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices/ListChildren.
SoapException Details: <detail />
Stack Trace:
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Proxy.Reporting.ReportingService.ListChildren(String Item, Boolean Recursive)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.RosettaReportUploader.CheckForProjectFolder(PrivateData data, String projectName, ProjectCreationContext context)
-- end Inner Exception --
--- end Exception entry ---
```

Comment: What version of TFS?  What version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the most relevant part of your exception stack:

> Failed to retrieve projects from the
>   report server. Please check that the
>   SQL Server Reporting Services Web and
>   Windows services are running and you
>   have sufficient privileges for
>   creating a project.

Make sure you are a content manager on reporting services by going to http://deltadev/reports
and looking at the security page.  Making yourself a TFS Admin does not automatically give you permissions in Reporting Services.  This has to be done separately.  Same for SharePoint by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Visual Studio 2008 SP1 installed.  Without SP1, you may get this error during project creation.